# v-rep Bubble Rob tutorial issues

Tags: simulation, robotics

I am extrememly new to v-rep (a robotic simulation software) and am trying to become familiar with the system by going through several of the tutorials. However, I have gotten stuck by the very first tutorial, Bubble Rob.

If you load the actual Bubble Rob scene in the tutorial folder, you can see that once the 'sensingNose' reaches one of the cylinders, Bubble Rob backs off and tries another direction. However, in my scene, after following through with the directions, Bubble Rob continues going forward until he is touching the cylinder and becomes stuck. (AKA the sensing Nose is not stopping him.)

The error that shows up when the simulation is running says:
29: Object does not exist (simSetJointTargetVelocity)

Any thoughts as to what I may have done wrong and why the fucction above does not exist? I have checked as may of the properties as I can, but it is entirely possible that I missed a step. Figuring out where I went wrong will help me understand more of the program, but I don't know enough about it's functionality currently, to find this on my own. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution after messing around in the program; the object simSetJointTargetVelocity was referencing an incorrect handle which had been typed into the program wrong.